# OpenSSL TLS gzip compression

Tags: ssl, openssl, gzip, tls1.3

How can I compress the SSL communication via OpenSSL uzing the gzip compression?

I didn't find any solution in OpenSSL documentation

Answer (score 2):

gzip compression is not defined for TLS, only deflate is - which is very similar, but not the same. But, since you also tag TLS 1.3 - the support for compression was removed in TLS 1.3 standard.

Comment: In lower protocols OpenSSL implements deflate only if configured and built with the 'zlib' option which has not been the default since open attacks like CRIME in 2012, and that library is linked usually dynamically but statically is possible, and of course it is used only if also implemented by the other endpoint and in 1.1.0 (2016) up you must also call `SSL_[CTX_]clear_options` with `SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION`. Also bcp195/rfc7525 recommends against it.

Comment: And is it possible somehow to explicitely use gzip in TLS1.2? Zlib enables gzip compression and as u mentioned, openssl supports zlib. I can't find a way to use zlib (used by openssl) so that the compression of TLS/SSL is in gzip format.

Comment: @FandaNovotny: *"Zlib enables gzip compression"* - zlib implements deflate, zlib and gzip - which are all very similar but not the same. gzip was not defined for use as SSL compression and it does not make sense since there is no advantage to deflate (basically just additional overhead due to gzip header). I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve here which is not better solved by compressing the data at the application level (like content-encoding in HTTP) instead of the TLS level.